# Dart convert int variable to string

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to convert an integer variable

```
var int counter = 0;
```

into a string variable

```
var String $counter = "0";
```

I searched but I only found something like

```
var myInt = int.parse('12345');
```

that doesn't work with

```
var myInt = int.parse(counter);
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Use `toString` and/or `toRadixString`

```
  int intValue = 1;
  String stringValue = intValue.toString();
  String hexValue = intValue.toRadixString(16);
```

or, as in the commment

```
  String anotherValue = 'the value is $intValue';
```

Comment: You can also use String interpolation to convert it, it's a little more concise:

`String stringValue = '$intValue';`

Answer (score 28):

### // String to int

```
String s = "45";
int i = int.parse(s);
```

### // int to String

```
int j = 45;
String t = "$j";
```

// If the latter one *looks weird*, look into string interpolation on https://dart.dev

Answer (score 13):

You can use the .toString() function in the int class.

```
int age = 23;
String tempAge = age.toString();
```

then you can simply covert integers to the Strings.