# Printing a class item of integer type in flutter

Tags: class, flutter, int

Is there a specific method to show integer value in flutter.
I have a code snippet similar to :

class with integer value:

```
class item{
  item({
    this.int_number
  });
  int int_number=1;
}
```

To print an int value in flutter, we usually use `Text("$number")`

but when trying similar method to print the class value :

```
Text("$item.int_number")
```

The number isn't printed correctly. but only data about `$item`

Is there a direct solution to this problem ?? to print int values that is a class item.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Text("${item.int_number}")`

to print the values of instances like `obj.value` you need to wrap it in `{}`

thus you can use `print("${obj.value}");`

**EDIT:**

Tested this code on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/)

```
void main() {
  var item = Item(intNumber: 5);
  print("${item.intNumber}");
  print(item);
}

class Item {
  Item({this.intNumber});
  int intNumber = 1;

  toString() => "Item (int_number = $intNumber)";
}
```

---

So you should be able to use

```
Text('${item.intNumber}')
```

or

```
Text('$item')
```

Comment: It is showing an error, 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Comment: can you provide the complete code? the piece where you are initializing the value.

Answer (score 2):

**Use `toString`** to converting int variable into String

For Example  :

```
  int intValue = 1;
```

I will use this in `Text` like this

```
Text("Value is:" + intValue.toString)
```

For more info try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954182/flutter-convert-int-variable-to-string)