# Flutter - String to Int, then int to String

Tags: flutter

I want to do a simple conversion: Integer to String. Like this.

```
   String select= (int.parse(widget.data['object']['element'])+1).toString();
```

But return this error

> Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Anybody know what is the error?

Comment: Try this way `int data = int.parse(widget.data['object']['element'] + 1;
 String select="$data";`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter convert int variable to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954182/flutter-convert-int-variable-to-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this way**

```
int data = int.parse(widget.data['object']['element'] + 1);

String select=data.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think widget.data['object']['element'] value is already int.

Try

```dart
(widget.data['object']['element'] +1).toString();
```