# Is there any solution to make this code work

Tags: flutter, dart, e-commerce

new Text(card_prod_qty),

Whenever i use this i get an error stated

type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Please help me solve it

Comment: Can you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this [Flutter convert int variable to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954182/flutter-convert-int-variable-to-string) has the solution to your question,

basically you could just use card_prod_qty.toString()

Answer (score 0):

The Text widget displays a string of text.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html

Considering the `card_prod_qty` variable is not a `string`, so you need to convert it.

```
card_prod_qty.toString()
```

So, just change

```
new Text(card_prod_qty),
```

to

```
new Text(card_prod_qty.toString()),
```

Comment: you're welcome :) If our answer has solved your problem please consider accepting it