# Converting int data to string returns null - Flutter Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a text field in which if one of the users enters a number it saves to the firestore as an integer.  When I try returning the data as a string it says null, even when there is int data for that specific user.

Here is the code for saving the data:

```
onPressed: () async {
                    try {
                      final String uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('UserNames')
                          .doc(uid)
                          .update({
                        "plastics": int.parse(_plasticController.text),
                      });
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    } catch (e) {}
                  },
```

And here is my failed attempt at converting it to String and attempting to display it:

First I made a future:

```
final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance; //
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    Future<String> getPlasticNum() async {
      final CollectionReference users = firestore.collection('UserNames');

      final String uid = auth.currentUser.uid;

      final result = await users.doc(uid).get();

      return result.data()['plastics'];
    }
```

Then I tried to display it:

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: getPlasticNum(),
          builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
            return Text(snapshot.data.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(color: Palette.lightGreen, fontSize: 20));
          },
        ),
```

Comment: So, what's wrong with what you've written so far?  Please edit the question to explain what isn't working the way you expect.  If there is an error message, copy it into the question.  I also suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DougStevenson I edited the problem to hopefully make it more clear on the fact that my attempt at returning the int data as a string returns null, even when there is data for that current user. Does that make it easier?

Comment: You should add some debug logging to make sure you got the data from the document that you expected.  You should also probably read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954182/flutter-convert-int-variable-to-string

Comment: If the answer is helped you, now you can upvote :)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64434263/10659482

Comment: @Akif Just did it, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Future<String> getPlasticNum()
```

In here, you tried to get a String value. So you need to convert your data to String.

```
  return result.data()['plastics'].toString();
```